# merging really not that large data.tables immediately results in R being killed

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I have 32GB of ram on this machine, but I can get R killed faster than anybody ;)

#### example

The goal here is to achieve an `rbind()` of two data.tables using functions that make use of data.table's efficiency.

input:

```
rm(list=ls())
gc()
```

output:

```
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells 1604987 85.8    2403845  128.4   2251281  120.3
Vcells 3019405 23.1  537019062 4097.2 468553954 3574.8
```

input:

```
tmp.table <- data.table(X1=sample(1:7,4096000,replace=TRUE),
                           X2=as.factor(sample(1:2,4096000,replace=TRUE)),
                           X3=sample(1:1000,4096000,replace=TRUE),
                           X4=sample(1:256,4096000,replace=TRUE),
                           X5=sample(1:16,4096000,replace=TRUE),
                           X6=rnorm(4096000))

setkey(tmp.table,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6)

join.table <- data.table(X1 = integer(), X2 = factor(), 
                         X3 = integer(), X4=integer(),
                         X5 = integer(), X6 = numeric())

setkey(join.table,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6)

tables()
```

output:

```
     NAME            NROW  MB COLS              KEY              
[1,] join.table         0   1 X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6 X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6
[2,] tmp.table  4,096,000 110 X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6 X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6
Total: 111MB
```

input:

```
join.table <- merge(join.table,tmp.table,all.y=TRUE)
```

output:

Ha! Nope. RStudio restarts the session.

#### question

What's going on here? Explicitly setting the factor levels in `join.table` had no effect. `rbind()` instead of `merge()` didn't help--exact same behavior. I have done way more complicated and bulky things related to this data without any problems.

#### version info

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"

$nickname
[1] "Frisbee Sailing"

> rstudio::versionInfo()
$version
[1] ‘99.9.9’

$mode
[1] "server"
```

Data.table is version 1.8.11.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you merge the empty `join.table` with the `tmp.table`?

Comment: I'm expecting the same results as `rbind()`. I'll edit to include that.

Comment: While `data.table` shouldn't segfault, merging like this should just return `tmp.table`... Also, your issue manifests with much smaller tables and also segfaults with `rbind` on my machine. But if you try on a very small `data.table` you're left with an exact copy of the initial table.

Comment: @Justin This is part of a larger script that is unifying some data in other formats and putting them all together into a big data.table. I realize this is somewhere in the R Inferno but I'm only doing it once.

Comment: If R is crashing, it seems like you should report this bug to the package maintainers (esp. since they're so responsive)

Comment: Works fine for me with rstudio_0.97.551, R version 3.0.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), & data.table_1.8.10.

Comment: @hadley, reported as https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5355&group_id=240&atid=975

Comment: This question is about a bug and has been reported. Thank you

Comment: I see this as a good question: reproducible code, version numbers etc. I don't see how the close reason "This question is about a bug" applies because OP didn't *know* it was a bug; i.e. the *question* isn't about a bug, the *answer* is. For example, the answer may have been that different syntax should be used. I'm not voting to close and have asked in the chat room as to etiquette here. Questions like this add to the knowledge base on S.O. afaics. If the question was about a bug then it should be closed, but it wasn't.

Comment: @MattDowle: I can understand where you're coming from, but segfaults are always bugs.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sure, but in general exactly what and where was the bug (RStudio or data.table) and might there be a workaround (a different command/syntax to use in the meantime)?  I know the close reason is there but the danger in following it too literally and closing the question is that it may discourage users from asking about problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update: This has been fixed in commit 1123 of [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1123):

> o  `rbindlist` with at least one factor column along with the presence of at least one empty `data.table` resulted in *segfault* (or in linux/mac reported an error related to hash tables). This is now fixed, #5355. Thanks to Trevor Alexander for reporting on SO (and mnel for filing the bug report): [merging really not that large data.tables immediately results in R being killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591433/merging-really-not-that-large-data-tables-immediately-results-in-r-being-killed)

---

This can be reproduced with a single row  `data.table` with a `factor` column and a zero-row data.table with a factor column.

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(x=factor(1), key='x')
B <- data.table(x=factor(), key='x')
merge(B, A, all.y=TRUE)

# Rstudio -> R encountered fatal error
#  R Gui -> R for windoze GUI has stopped working
```

Using `debugonce(data.table:::merge.data.table)` this can be traced to the line `rbind(dt,yy)` which the equivalent of

```
rbind(B,A)
```

which, if you run it, will give the same error.

This has been reported to the package authors as issue [#5355](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5355&group_id=240&atid=975)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in 1.8.10 or 1.8.11 on a Mac 10.9. Neither in RGui or Terminal

Comment: I will add OS info also.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for filing the report and linking back here. I've upped its priority.